# Change the path where wordpress plugins are uploaded

Tags: plugins, paths

Currently my plugins are getting uploaded to `public_html/sitename/wp-content/plugins` instead of `public_html/wp-content/plugins`. Is there any way that I can change the path where word press uploads the plugins?

I had moved my site to the root folder and hence this issue arose.

Comment: How did you move your site? If you did that properly, WordPress should have updated filepaths on its own.

Comment: I used back up buddy. As it stands now, any plugin that I upload gets uploaded to public_html/oldsite/wp-content/plugins instead of public_html/wp-content/plugins.  I even tried uploading the plugin manually to public_html/wp-content/plugins.  However, plugin page does not detect it and so I am unable to install it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> General`. What are the URLs for **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**?

Answer (score 15):

You can change the Plugins directory using [constants defined in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content):

> Set `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to the full local path of this directory (no
>   trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );
> ```
>
> Set `WP_CONTENT_URL` to the full URI of this directory (no trailing
>   slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');
> ```
>
> Set `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` to the full local path of this directory (no
>   trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
> ```
>
> Set `WP_PLUGIN_URL` to the full URI of this directory (no trailing
>   slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins');
> ```
>
> If you have compability issues with plugins Set `PLUGINDIR` to the full
>   local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'PLUGINDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
> ```

### But wait!

If the need to define these paths originates from moving your installation from a subdirectory to the document root, your problem is very likely that you didn't make that move properly. Please reference [this Codex entry about giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: I added the lines define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content'); in my wp-config.php and then removed it. But my site has now broken. PLEASE HELP

Comment: None of the plugins show up on the site

Comment: Try adding http:// to the start of WP_CONTENT_URL: 
`define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content';);`

Comment: now link to WP docs is: https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/