# 3 blogs same installation, without WP MU

Tags: php, redirect, htaccess

I've to create 3 blogs (different **DOMAINS**) on the same wordpress installation (I **cannot use WP MU**, unfortunately) so I came out with the idea that I could use categories, instead, so... every blog has its own category (categories would be used only for that.) (eg: **blog1.com = blog1**) and urls must go like this:

**blog1.com/1891/23/some-title/**

**blog2.com/1892/25/some-other-title/**

Is there some other way to do it? a plugin, maybe?! Because if I do it this way, I've to redirect a lot of stuff.. have to create a custom homepages etc. could it be done with htaccess or needs to be php? I don't even know if it is possible, and how good will it work... What you think? I need your thoughts on this.

thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90621/73)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to run 3 separate domains on the same files but different databases you can do something like this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-domains-using-one-wp-install-not-wpmu

You then have to consider if you want separate uploads folders and style sheets. If so, you'll have to define a constant so that you can tell the page which style sheet to use and add some code and apply a hook to send each site's uploads to the correct location. I suppose plugins might also be an issue too, but you could define a bunch of constants in wp-config.php and over-ride defaults if you needed to.

[Change the path where wordpress plugins are uploaded](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74958/change-the-path-where-wordpress-plugins-are-uploaded)

Comment: yes, this seems interesting.